# Variable scoping in Module

Tags: scoping

I don't understand why $a$ and $b$ are not local in the following code:

```
Clear[lint];
lint[f_, x_] := Module[{a, b}, f /. Replace[x, {a_, b_} -> a -> b]];

Clear[a];
lint[x, {x, t}] (* returns t, as I would expect *)

a = 3;
lint[x, {x, t}] (* returns x *)

Clear[a]; a=3;
lint1[f_, x_] := Module[{a, b}, f /. Replace[x, {a_, b_} :> a -> b]]; (* returns t *)
```

It appears that the occurrence of $a$ in the pattern inside the replace is being interpreted in the outer scope. Why is that?

Update: Having read @szabolcs comment and the first answer, I still don't quite understand. First, the documentation for `Rule` says that "Symbols that occur as pattern names in lhs are treated as local to the rule.". Fine, that's what the comment said. But if they are local, then why is $3$ substituted for $a$ in the second example above?

Second, why does using `:>` solve the problem? The only difference between `Rule` and `RuleDelayed`, as far as I can see, is when the *right-hand* symbols are evaluated. So why does this change the behavior? (See the new fourth example above).

Comment: Your use of `Module` is unnecessary. If you use `RuleDelayed` instead of `Rule`, then the pattern variables are automatically localized. `lint2[f_, x_] := f /. Replace[x, {a_, b_} :> a -> b]`

Comment: The question is "why", not how to fix..

Comment: No time for a full answer, but in short: `Rule` itself is a sort of scoping construct in Mathematica and it will protect symbols that are used as pattern names in its LHS from being renamed by Module.

Comment: @szabolcs I updated my question to respond to your comment --- there are still some things here that don't make sense, even in light of what you say about `Rule`.

Comment: If using version 9, might try setting SetSystemOptions["StrictLexicalScoping"->True]` and see if that changes things in a useful way.

Comment: Regarding the update: The difference is that with `Rule` the symbol `a` **does not appear on the rhs**, because the rhs is evaluated before `Rule` "sees it". So the rule is: `{a_, b_} -> (3 -> b)`. Since the symbols `a` and `b` occur as pattern names in the lhs of this rule, they are indeed treated as local to the rule, but this localisation happens *after* the evaluation of the rhs. `RuleDelayed` has the `HoldRest` attribute, so the rhs doesn't get evaluated and the rule acts as you expect.

Comment: @rogerl Yes, I agree with you that this is weird, confusing, non-obvious, and probably a fault of Mathematica ... Here's a clearer example: `a = "outside";
Module[{a = "inside"}, 1 /. a_Integer -> a]`.  This one returns `"outside"`, not `"inside"`.  We told you that both `Module` and `Rule` do some kind of localization.  But the end result is that `a` doesn't get localized *at all* and it's evaluated to its global value.  *Of course this is extremely confusing!*  But it's how the system works (i.e. doing "localization" via renaming) and we cannot change it.

Comment: Just so you don't get the impression that no one else finds this behaviour upsetting and user-unfriendly ;-)  We learned to live with it.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Does that option have any known bad side-effects?  I assume there might easily be some internally used code that will get broken if we use it ...

Comment: @rogerl As for the why, the main reason is that `Module` does localization by renaming variables before evaluation, as you can see by evaluating `Module[{x}, x]`.  However, it does not rename everything.  Things inside other scoping constructs inside `Module` do not always get renamed.  I do not fully understand when this renaming happens and when it doesn't, nor why (and when) it is necessary.  It a very dark corner of Mathematica.  The rest is explained by the answers: since `Rule` is a kind of scoping construct, it prevents Module from renaming `a`, so we still have `a` instead ...

Comment: ... of `a$123` (i.e. the "localized" version).  `a` is a global symbol which has a value, to which it gets evaluated.  Again the thing to pay attention to here is that there aren't really any local and global variables in Mathematica, only renamed or non-renamed ones.  (Side note: What `Block` does is that it temporarily removes the definitions associated with symbols, but the symbols themselves stay the same.)

Comment: @szabolcs Thanks. I think your explanation is the clearest and most complete, but I can't accept it because it's not in the form of an Answer. Can you make it so? And yes, this seems pretty ugly. But at least now I understand what is happening.

Comment: @Szabolcs Unknown as to what it might do. I always have it enabled for more than two years and have seen no ill effects at all in my code. We believe it cannot be enabled for building Wolfram|Alpha since that seems to correlate with a crash problem. But the details have yet to be sorted out.

Answer (score 13):

As Szabolcs say in comments, "`Rule` itself is a sort of scoping construct in *Mathematica* and it will protect symbols that are used as pattern names in its LHS from being renamed by `Module`." Let us check this:

```
Clear["`*"];
Module[{a, b}, {a_, b_} -> a -> b]

(* =>  {a_, b_} -> a -> b *)
```

One can see that `Module` has not renamed `a` and `b` as Szabolcs state. But this protection takes place only if both variables on LHS are defined via `Blank` (*Mathematica* 8.0.4):

```
Clear["`*"];
Module[{a, b}, {a_, b} -> a -> b]

(* => {a$_, b$96} -> a$ -> b$96 *)
```

Here we see a limitation of `Module`'s cleverness...

Comment: This is clear in the `Module` docs.. Module substitutes new symbols for each of the local variables that appear anywhere in expr *except as local variables in scoping constructs.* -- still a bit disturbing

Comment: @george2079 Could you explain the second example in my answer?