# I define a variable as local to a module BUT then the module uses its global value! Why?

Tags: scoping, core-language

I have a question about modules and local variables.

Here's my example:

```
h = 5;

Module[{a, h}, a[h_]= h^2; a[4]]

(*Out[2] = 25*)
```

I expected the module to return 16 and not 25! I believed h to be a LOCAL variable of the module!

I know that the following alternatives work and return correctly 16

```
Module[{a, h}, a[h_] := h^2; a[4]]
Module[{a, h}, a[h] = h^2; a[4]]
Module[{a, j}, a[j_] = j^2; a[4]]  (* with j a variable not previously defined *)
Block[{a, h}, a[h_] = h^2; a[4]]
```

Question: why does the module behave like that? i.e. why does it return 25 and not 16?

P.S. I am running out of variables and I am then resorting to modules to avoid errors due to variables defined more than once. I played a bit with modules to check their properties and I ran in this example.

Comment: I assume in your code you used a semicolon instead of a comma between `h^2` and `a[4]`, otherwise you'd get an error about giving 3 arguments to `Module`.  I edited it to fix the problem.

Comment: yes, thank you!!

Comment: @JasonB Yes there seem to be many solutions, however this exampled revealed to me that I was not understanding something properly and I wanted to know what that something was in order to be more confident in using Modules etc... Anyway for the time being I might just as well create more variable names.
Actually I wanted to use modules also to have a cleaner program.

Comment: `Module` is a fantastic way to have a clean program, but your problem here is using `=` (`Set`) instead of `:=` (`SetDelayed`).  In my opinion, there are very few instances where it's better to use `Set`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(42351)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42351/121)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### What happens and why

As Daniel Lichtblau pointed out in comments, this behavior can also be viewed as a flaw in the current behavior / design / implementation of lexical scoping in Mathematica. However, it may be useful still to understand on a deeper level what happens, since it can be explained rather easily from the core rules of how lexical scoping operates in the default mode in current (and past) versions of Mathematica.

While Mr.Wizard already discussed part of what's happening in his (now deleted) answer, I think it pays off to understand this from a somewhat different angle. `Set` is a scoping construct, and as such, it protects its bindings from possible actions of the outer scoping constructs. The general mechanics of how this happens has been discussed in  [our answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20766/enforcing-correct-variable-bindings-and-avoiding-renamings-for-conflicting-varia), but let's focus on the specifics here.

One thing to understand is what is the action of the outer scoping construct (`Module`) in this case. The action is variable binding, that is, renaming of variable `h` to a newly produced local symbol looking like `h$123`, everywhere in the code, before the body of the scoping construct (`Module`) is allowed to execute. It is this action that `Set` has to guard its arguments against.

The second point here is that while the protection is needed for `Set`, the only function in position to enforce such protection is in fact `Module`, just because it is the only one being evaluated at that stage. So, `Module`'s internal code has to detect `Set` and protect its arguments. This is very similar to other cases, but while there things get renamed, here, on the opposite, such renaming `h -> h$123` has to be prevented.

Now, here is one way to show that this is indeed what happens: use a standard idiom to fool the inner scoping construct detection mechanism:

```
Module[{a, h}, Set @@ Hold[a[h_], h^2]; a[4]]

(* 16 *)
```

Now, `Module` can't detect `Set` inside, and therefore `h` is being successfully bound to the `Module`-generated variable, and we get what we'd naively expect.

So, to summarize: we have here the same situation as with other cases described in the linked post, but the main difference is that while there outer scoping constructs were in charge of making renamings, here it is the opposite: in the case of `Set`, the outer lexical scoping constructs are responsible for *prevention* of such renamings. In this particular case, `Module` is then forced to disable its own binding mechanism.

Note that `SetDelayed` is different, because while the `Module` behavior would be the same, `SetDelayed` makes its own bindings with it's r.h.s., which effectively localize the pattern variable correctly. Note also that this issue only holds for lexical scoping constructs, and dynamic scoping isn't affected by this.

### Ways out

#### 1. Use "StrictLexicalScoping" -> True system options setting

Thanks to Daniel's work, we have now an option available to change it. If you set

```
SetSystemOptions["StrictLexicalScoping" -> True];
```

Then the result is what it was expected to be:

```
Module[{a, h}, a[h_] = h^2; a[4]]

(* 16 *)
```

#### 2. Use "standard" techniques to fool the inner scoping construct detection mechanism

This is as described above, but any such technique would do. See the linked post for some of the most commonly used. Admittedly, the need to use such tricks in such a case is a pain in the neck.

### Summary

What happens can be viewed as a design / implementation flaw. Thanks to the work of Daniel Lichtblau, now there is an option available to switch to a mode which is free of these flaws. OTOH, the above behavior does not look like a plain bug to me, but rather a consistent behavior fully explained by the rules of how lexical scoping constructs operate in current versions of Mathematica in default mode. I have tried to explain the logic behind this behavior from the deeper principles of how scoping constructs currently behave in the default mode. It is another issue that those rules may be considered flawed, and we've seen discussions of many other instances exposing these flaws, here on SE.

Comment: I just noticed that Simon Woods made a comment to Mr. Wizard's answer (now deleted), essentially the same as what I have described here. I didn't see that comment before posting this.

Comment: I am not sure I understood (because I am not an expert user). Here is an example that "works" and uses Set instead of SetDelayed:
    h = 10;
    Module[{h}, abc[h]=h^2;abc[4]]
    (* Out[2] = 16 *)

Here is the example that does not work
    h = 10;
    Module[{h}, abc[h_]=h^2;abc[4]]
    (* Out[4] = 25 *)

Thanks!

Comment: @pan_e_gaban I suggest to read the linked post, which explains parts omitted here. Also, read the documentation of `Set`, to understand its evaluation semantics. And read on scoping constructs in the documentation, to understand how `Module` implements lexical scoping. Basically, `Module` localizes variables by renaming them in code, with local symbols with unique names that it creates. This renaming is prevented in this case, as I described. Now, at the time `Module` evaluates its body, the symbol `h` remains unrenamed, and is then taken from the surrounding (global in this case) environment.

Comment: @pan_e_gaban, neither of those works in that neither of them returns 16.  When you define `abc[h]=h^2`, you aren't defining a function of h.

Comment: @pan_e_gaban The evaluation semantics of `Set` is then responsible for the rest: `Set` evaluates its r.h.s. *at the time of assignment*, which results in r.h.s. being evaluated with the global value of `h`. Now, in your first example in your comment, there are no pattern variables, and therefore no bindings to protect (only pattern variables are considered the local variables which induce bindings and make `Set` a scoping construct). In any case, you've run into a fairly advanced stuff, don't expect to fully understand it without getting a deeper understanding of scoping and related issues.

Comment: @JasonB and Leonid, reading your answers and comments and going back to previous posts you linked I started having a feel with the renaming operation performed in some scoping constructs. Also I now start to see why the Mathematica documentation puts so much emphasis on protection and so forth! These answers and discussion have certainly helped me to grow as a Mathematica user. Thanks!

Comment: @pan_e_gaban Was glad to help! Thanks for the accept. Just keep in mind, that generally, it is a good practice to wait with accepting an answer for a little bit, to encourage others contribute more answers.

Comment: No need to dance around this: it's a flaw in the implementation of the scoping mechanism. Set `SetSystemOptions["StrictLexicalScoping" -> True];` and it gives 16 (but you already knew that..)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I knew in general, but it didn't occur to me to test it in this particular case. Here I tried to describe the current default model (the old one, before your work), and actually it is kind of logical for what it does. It's another question that, from the language design point of view, it is indeed a flaw - but I'd say, more flaw in that design, than in implementation. If we assume that the design is that `Set` and `SetDelayed` protect their bindings no matter what, then the implementation works fine. I think that if something is flawed, it is this design.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau But I have not looked at internal code, let alone understand it in all detail, while you did, so I may well be wrong here. Perhaps, my main point here was to enforce Occam's razor principle and show how the observed behavior can be consistently explained from a smaller set of principles of how scoping constructs operate currently (in the default mode) in Mathematica. It would be nice if your StrictLexicalScoping mode could become a default some time soon.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I have added a note with your suggestion to my post - see if you agree with what I wrote, or please feel free to edit to your liking.

Comment: Small correction: Yes, I have looked at the internal code. No, I do not understand it in all detail. If I did, I'd almost surely need to be institutionalized.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau All right, correction accepted :). I should be very thankful that I never had the time and will power to try looking at it myself.

Comment: As for your use of a small set of principles to explain a consistent design, yeah, I think I agree that you probably have it right, and certainly that is a useful process. The problem is that the design has caused considerable trouble in terms of surprising and sometimes difficult to work around issues. Or possibly it is implementation in some places; even with the explanation you give, I'm not entirely convinced the renaming always works as advertised.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau For me, the main value in such deeper digging is that occasionally, one can find constructive uses of such behavior. Because really, even though it is flawed, it can be entirely controlled by the user (who has a clue of how these things work), like those techniques to fool that mechanism in some cases.  So experienced users knowing what they are doing can take advantage of that. Sealing the scoping more tightly is likely to close a number of such possibilities. Still, for the majority of users, the correct but less controllable behavior is better.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau As to working correctly in all cases, I am not even sure that the "transparent" model of lexical scoping where all bindings are programmatically exposed and we have transparent (say to pattern-matching) expressions, allows that even in theory. You will probably be able to construct counter-examples with leaks no matter how sophisticated the new design of lexical scoping would be, if we keep this kind of transparency. At least I wouldn't be very surprised if that were true. So the question may be more about solving it for the vast majority of actual uses, than completely.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Which is what your new lexical scoping mode actually does, as far as I understand.

Comment: All correct. "StrictLexicalScoping" should more aptly be called "StricterLexicalScoping" but it is by no means foolproof and there are known soft spots.

Answer (score 8):

Great question.  My first reaction is that this shouldn't happen.  `h` appears explicitly inside the `Module` and it should be substituted with the localized equivalent, e.g. `h$123`, even if it is held:

```
Module[{h}, HoldComplete[h^2]]
```

> ```
> HoldComplete[h$6992^2]
> ```

However named patterns in constructs such as `Set` and `Rule` are exempt from this substitution:

```
Module[{h}, Hold[h_ -> h^2]]
```

> ```
> Hold[h_ -> h^2]
> ```

```
Module[{h}, Hold[f[h_] = h^2]]
```

> ```
> Hold[f[h_] = h^2]
> ```

This is related to:

- [Enforcing correct variable bindings and avoiding renamings for conflicting variables in nested scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/121)

Until now I did not realize that this affected constructs without a Hold attribute.  That is I knew that `Module` handles `Function`, `SetDelayed`, and `RuleDelayed` differently:

```
Module[{x}, Function[x, x^2]]
```

> ```
> Function[x, x^2]
> ```

```
Module[{x}, f[x_] := x^2]
?f
```

> ```
> f[x_] := x^2
> ```

```
Module[{x}, x_ :> x^2]
```

> ```
> x_ :> x^2
> ```

This actually makes sense as the `x` is already being localized by these constructs and additional substitution by `Module` would only result in e.g.:

> ```
> Function[x$123, x$123^2]
> ```

However in the case of `Set` or `Rule`, which do not have hold attributes, this is problematic, as these are not localizing constructs as correctly recognized by the syntax highlighter.   Daniel Lichtblau wrote plainly:

> No need to dance around this: it's a flaw in the implementation of the scoping mechanism. Set `SetSystemOptions["StrictLexicalScoping" -> True];` and it gives 16.

So it seems that my first reaction was correct, and this *shouldn't* happen but does.

---

### Further thoughts and exploration

Leonid comments below that `Set` and `Rule` are still scoping constructs.  I do not contest this.  As noted the difference is in the evaluation behavior controlled by hold attributes.

Let us ask the question:

- How should the right-hand-side Symbols in `Set` and `Rule` be handled within `Module`?

The existing default behavior leaves both the LHS and RHS `x` unchanged in *this case* which results in the RHS instance evaluating to the global value of `x` if it exists:

```
Module[{x}, x_ -> x]

x_ -> x
```

However a slight change results in different behavior:

```
Module[{x, y}, x_ -> x y]
```

> ```
> x$_ -> x$ y$748
> ```

Here the [automatic renaming](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/121) mechanism kicks in and changes `x` to `x$` on both sides of the `Rule`.

If as in `SetDelayed` and `RuleDelayed` the RHS is not expected to immediately evaluate this difference in renaming often will not matter.  However with `Set` and `Rule` where the RHS *is* expected to evaluate this inconsistency is troubling.  One cannot generally rely on the behavior illustrated in the original question as it will break if this renaming is activated:

```
h = 5; i = 7;

Module[{h, i}, h_ -> h^2]

Module[{h, i}, h_ -> i*h]
```

> ```
> h_ -> 25
>
> h$_ -> h$ i$787
> ```

From a user's perspective the simple introduction of `i` in the RHS should *not* result in an entirely different evaluation characteristic, yet it does.  (This affects `Set` as well.)  It would be desirable to have consistency in this behavior, and it seems that is exactly what Daniel's System Option provides:

```
SetSystemOptions["StrictLexicalScoping" -> True];

h = 5; i = 7;

Module[{h, i}, h_ -> h^2]

Module[{h, i}, h_ -> i*h]
```

> ```
> h$_ -> h$^2
>
> h$_ -> h$ i$1334
> ```

Now the `h` is renamed to `h$` on both sides of both rules.

Comment: Isn't it another example of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20766/enforcing-correct-variable-bindings-and-avoiding-renamings-for-conflicting-varia/20776#20776)? Using `Module[{a, h}, Set @@ {a[h_], h^2}; a[4]]` avoids the problem by "hiding" the inner scoping construct from `Module`

Comment: @Simon Updated.  Please tell me if this answer makes sense now, and if it has value.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't quite agree with your conclusions here. And here is why. The fact that `Rule` and `Set` aren't `HoldAll`, does not prevent them from being scoping constructs. The defining property of a scoping construct is that, apart from special evaluation stage and semantics, it also has a precluding *variable binding* stage. That `Rule` and `Set` are not `HoldAll`, influence their *evaluation* semantics, but not *binding* semantics, which is for them in fact the same, as for `RuleDelayed` and `SetDelayed`, respectively. Namely, protect their bindings from outer scoping constructs.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard So, during the binding stage, both l.h.s. and r.h.s. pattern variables are being protected. It is this "protection request", that forces `Module` to disable its binding procedure for these inner local variables. In other words, from the binding perspective, `h` remains local also for `Rule` and `Set`, and the fact that the global value is used for it during evaluation, is an effect of *evaluation* semantics, and happens during evaluation stage, which follows the binding stage.

Comment: @Leonid Thank you for your wisdom as always.  I am/was semi-aware of that point which is why I chose the weasel-words "localizing constructs."  I think somewhere in there I have a valid point and I'll try to think of how to improve this.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard So, according to the rules of how scoping constructs work and resolve conflicts in inner constructs, the observed behavior is actually correct, when we recall that `Set` is 1. Scoping construct requesting to protect its variable bindings (both l.h.s. and r.h.s, this has nothing to do with its evaluation semantics), and 2. Has evaluation semantics which in fact evaluates the r.h.s during assignment.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Oh, I am sure you do, you always have valid points. I actually think we've never went so deep into these sorts of issues before in our discussions here on SE, this is certainly one of the darker corners of the language. We shouldn't go too deep, though, if we want to heed Daniel's warning and avoid the outcome of being institutionalized.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, I hadn't properly appreciated the real issue here, that the renaming exemption should not apply to unheld constructs.

Comment: The StrictLexicalScoping option looks useful, though I wish it were implemented as a StrictLexicalModule function rather than a system option.

Comment: @Simon It's a sticky situation now.  If they change the default behavior to `"StrictLexicalScoping" -> True` certain legacy code will break, however I think that is the more consistent behavior as I attempt to illustrate in my latest update.  A *new* scoping function would solve this problem at the expensive of yet another function to wrangle; as a terse code fanatic I would *hate* the name `StrictLexicalModule` but what else do you call it?  `Local` perhaps?

Comment: @Leonid Please tell me if you find value in my latest update.

Comment: @SimonWoods Perhaps the exemption should not apply from the end user's point of view, but I was trying to make a point that this behavior is consistent with the general principles that underpin the lexical scoping machinery in Mathematica. If something has to be changed, that should be the core principles, not specific consequences  like this one, IMO. That's what Daniel's new option / mode does: it changes some of these principles, which affects a bunch of different cases at once. He was able to find a solution which resolved all or most of them at once.

Comment: @Leonid How do *you* think this should be handled hereafter?  I am tempted to include `SetSystemOptions["StrictLexicalScoping" -> True];` in my bug-fix `init.m` section but I don't like the fact that this will further separate the behavior of my system from the default that most people experience.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard And yes, of course, you have my vote. As to the settings, I don't really know. I think, in different situations, either one or the other may have advantages. I'd set StrictLexicalScoping to True, probably.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Actually, one thought that crossed my mind is that when I get a spare moment, I will try to write down those scoping rules, such that the set of those rules would explain all cases we discussed here on SE, as well as all other known cases. Having those rules would probably be useful, because presumably they would make it quite easy to predict the outcome in most or all cases. Although, *some* of them are indeed borderline bugs, like the one about nested bindings, that I discussed in the linked question.

Comment: (1) One thing about StrictLexicalScoping: it is not known to be bug free. Indeed, at least one serious bug showed up in it several months ago. It's since been fixed, but I'm not sure that fix went into version 10.0.2.

Comment: (2) The remark about SLS possibly breaking legacy code should also be taken to heart. I have it set in my development version of the Mathematica kernel, and that has shown a handful of places where code was indeed depending on the current (non-strict) behavior. I don't like that, but it's hard to blame people for availing themselves of the program as it actually behaves, regardless of (slightly vague) scoping documentation.

Comment: (3) The ultimate proof-of-close-to-correctness for SLS is the following. (1) With it set to True internally, build the Mathematica kernel. (2) Run the system test suite. (3) Build Wolfram|Alpha from that kernel. (4) Make sure it can be started. (5) Run the W|A sanity check tests. Before last summer I think we had only gotten through (3). More recently we went through (4) but I think (5) has been iffy (nobody has had time to diagnose as yet). Could be a bug still in the scoping itself. Could be more legacy code requiring the old behavior. Could be angry or capricious moon beams...

Comment: @Leonid, I was using the SE app on my phone and it hadn't updated to show your comments so my reply to Mr Wizard appears to be ignoring or disagreeing with you! I do see what you mean, `Set` and `Rule` are scoping constructs so the behaviour *is* consistent (though arguably undesirable), which is what I thought originally. I hope you manage to find time to write down that list of rules - it's a shame the official documentation doesn't go into the level of detail that you do in your contributions here.

Comment: @SimonWoods No problem :) Besides, I wasn't entirely sure I am right about all this. Yes, I think that the behavior is consistent with internal principles of how scoping operates in Mathematica, although that set of principles produces a system which in many cases exhibits undesirable behavior, as you said. I've made a long stream of comments here (now deleted), where I tried to expand on my vision of that. My main point is perhaps that the requirement for this system to be highly consistent with the rest of Mathematica (in particular, evaluation and pattern-matching) is pretty tough, and ...

Comment: @SimonWoods ... that it may not be easy to make a system which would always exhibit the behavior we desire. Because it can't be designed just on a case by case basis, and once you fix the principles, you can't change much, like in a very overdetermined system of equations. So, what may look like a bug or illogical behavior on the surface, in most cases is just a consequence of those rather non-obvious principles and their interplay. AFAIK, Daniel managed to modify this model consistently to behave much better, without making the design uglier.

Comment: @SimonWoods Re: write down the principles - I agree, I should sit down and do that, and then the rest of us will correct me where I am wrong. As to why those were not officially stated in the docs - I think, they are still considered more the implementation details. My guess is that the language designers were not ready to explicitly spec them, because the rules may change in the future, and not to encourage people to rely on these details too much (which seems like a reasonable strategy to me). That said, having those specs would certainly make our lives much easier. Hope to do this soon.