# How to scope `Pattern` labels in rules/set?

Tags: pattern-matching, scoping, rule, argument-patterns, internals

```
Module[{x},
 f@x_ = x;
 p@x_ := x;
 {x, x_, x_ -> x, x_ :> x}
 ]
?f
?p
```

gives

```
{x$17312, x$17312_, x_ -> x, x_ :> x}
f[x_]=x
p[x_]:=x
```

but I'd like to get

```
{x$17312, x$17312_, x$17312_ -> x$17312, x$17312_ :> x$17312}
f[x$17312_]=x$17312
p[x$17312_]:=x$17312
```

I thought `Module[{x}, body_]` operates something like the following, which would do what I want:

```
module[{x_Symbol}, body_] := ReleaseHold[Hold@body /. x -> Unique@x];
SetAttributes[module, HoldAll];

module[{x},
 f@x_ = x;
 p@x_ := x;
 {x, x_, x_ -> x, x_ :> x}
 ]
?f
?p
```

I guess there are some cases with nested scoping constructs that need to be considered for special treatment, but why can't it do the replacement in `Set, SetDelayed, Rule, RuleDelayed`?

---

Motivation

I want to use`f@x_ = Integrate[y^2, {y, 0, x}]` instead of `f@x_ := Evaluate@Integrate[y^2, {y, 0, x}]` and to be safe I want to scope the variable/pattern label `x` to something unique.

See also [Why does syntax highlighting in `Set` and `Rule` not color pattern names on the RHS?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119878/why-does-syntax-highlighting-in-set-and-rule-not-color-pattern-names-on-the)

Comment: [tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThingsOverview](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules.html) gives some details about scoping constructs

Comment: This question has a very similar goal http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1992/how-to-make-a-function-like-set-but-with-a-block-construct-for-the-pattern-name

Comment: About scoping in the `f@x_ := Evaluate@Integrate[y^2, {y, 0, x}]` case see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119972/280) answer of mine.

Comment: Related: [(72758)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72758/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `Set` isn't a scoping construct (SC), it is considered one by other SCs outer to it. [**ref / Set / Details[[-3]]**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) (thanks to [Alexey Popkov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/280/alexey-popkov) for correcting me).

Here it is inner to the `Module` and `Module` decides  not to interfere in this case (don't know why), but you can trick it:

```
Module[{x},
  Set @@ {f[x_], Integrate[y^2, {y, 0, x}]};
]

?f
```

> ```
> f[x$301_]=x$301^3/3
> ```

Further reading: [Enforcing correct variable bindings and avoiding renamings for conflicting variables in nested scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20776/5478)

Comment: You can trick it with inactivate too: `Module[{x}, f[x_] = x]~Inactivate~Set~Activate~Set`

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov right, I should rephrase that.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov done, thanks again.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov From what I understand, "scoping constructs" are not a "first-class" feature of the system anyways, right? It's only about forwarding correctly renamed (or unchanged), unevaluated symbols to the kernel when a global replacement rule is finally installed... An expression becomes a "scoping construct" when the symbol-renaming processes *treat* it as such (e.g. by leaving things untouched), no?

Comment: @masterxilo No, definitely scoping constructs like `Block`, `Module` and `With` do not leave things untouched! Only global replacement rules *may* work in this way, for example if we set the `HoldAllComplete` attribute for `f`, then by evaluating `f[x_] := g[x]` we create a global rule which will do transfer the argument of `f` to `g` untouched. Without this attribute it may be evaluated before the transfer. And since the system is *based* on the replacement rules they definitely **are** the first-class citizens!

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov What I was trying to say is that it is purely "by convention" that the renaming that e.g. `Module` does does not descend into pattern labels occurring in rules. We could easily define our own `Module` that doesn't care about the `scoping constructs` (like `Rule`, `Function`, `With`...) appearing within its body and does replacements in any case. `ReplaceAll` does this. C.f. the `module` I defined in the OP.

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been discussed before in

- [I define a variable as local to a module BUT then the module uses its global value! Why?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72758/121)

Regarding your motivation a solution of mine, which you linked to yourself, is shown in

- [How to make a function like Set, but with a Block construct for the pattern names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1992/how-to-make-a-function-like-set-but-with-a-block-construct-for-the-pattern-name)

What is left is to implement a `Module` alternative as you attempted, or to use some alternative to `Rule`, `Set`, etc., as shown in other answers.  I shall explore making a `Module` alternative more robust.  To pick apart your starting code:

1. `Unique@x` will evaluate `x`; this is unacceptable.
2. The local Symbol lacks the [`Temporary`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Temporary.html) attribute and will not be garbage-collected.
3. Only a single local Symbol may be specified.
4. There is no provision for assignments within the first parameter.

Here is my attempt to fix these limitations.

```
SetAttributes[module, HoldAll]

clean = Replace[#, (Set | SetDelayed)[s_Symbol, _] :> s, {2}] &;

module[{sets : (_Symbol | _Set | _SetDelayed) ..}, body_] :=
 (List @@ #; 
    Unevaluated[body] /. 
     List @@ MapAt[HoldPattern, {All, 1}] @ 
       Thread[clean[Hold[sets] :> #], Hold]) & @ Module[{sets}, Hold[sets]]
```

Now:

```
x = 1;
module[{x},
  f @ x_  = x;
  p @ x_ := x;
  {x, x_, x_ -> x, x_ :> x}
]
?f
?p
```

> ```
> {x$533, x$533_, x$533_ -> x$533, x$533_ :> x$533}
>
> f[x$533_]=x$533
>
> p[x$533_]:=x$533
> ```

And also:

```
module[{x, y = 3, z := Print["foo!"]},
  {x, y, x_, y_, x_ -> x y, x_ :> x, z_ :> x y}
]
```

> ```
> {x$533, 3, x$533_, y$533_, x$533_ -> 3 x$533, x$533_ :> x$533, 
>  z$533_ :> x$533 y$533}
> ```

Comment: please correct me if i am wrong but the following code works without having to use `clean` i.e. `Unevaluated[body] /. 
 List @@ (MapAt[HoldPattern, {All, 1}]@Thread[Hold[sets] :> #, Hold] &)@
   Module[{sets}, Hold[sets]]`

Comment: my bad, I found that clean is indeed required for displaying `y=3` in the second part

Comment: @AliHashmi I am pleased that you are not only reading my answers but looking for ways to correct and improve them. :-)  Please don't hesitate to make suggestions like this.  It will be good to work through them together.

Comment: thank you. actually i realized how blatantly wrong i was yet again. The `clean` function was to get the l.h.s symbols from the `Set` and `DelayedSet` definitions and then the thread is applied to get the rule `x` to `x$something` under Hold

Answer (score 2):

I think a third kind of behaviour would also be possible: it is debatable whether `f@x_ = x, x_ -> x` within `Module[{x}, ...` should not become `f@x_ = x$123, x_ -> x$123` because then the sequence

```
ClearAll[Global`x];
x = 1;
0 /. x_ -> x
```

would do the same whether executed in the global context or within a `Module[{x}, ...]`. It currently does not: *With a fresh kernel* (or after clearing `x`), the program gives 1 in the global context and `0` within a `Module[{x}, ...]`:

```
ClearAll[Global`x];
Module[{x}, x = 1; 0 /. x_ -> x]
```

Use `Hold, Unique, ReleaseHold` as you demonstrated if you want some specific renaming to happen within pattern labels of `Set, SetDelayed, Rule, RuleDelayed` - `Module` will not descend into these by design.

Comment: I get `1` in `Module` and in ``Global` `` context. What version are you using? Moreover, I think that would be really unexpected: `f@x_ = x$123` but why not `f[ x$123_ ]= x$123`? What do you think?

Comment: You have to ``ClearAll[Global`x]`` before running it in the Module. I am arguing for what you suggested, `f[ x$123_ ]= x$123` in the OP. But `f@x_ = x$123` would also make sense, because at the moment, `ClearAll[Global`x, Global`f]; x = 1; f@x_ = x; f@0` gives 1, but `ClearAll[Global`x, Global`f]; Module[{x}, x = 1; f@x_ = x;]; f@0` gives 0, just like with the `Rule` example I posted here.

Comment: Ah, right, my mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you need is the [`` LocalPatterns` ``](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/425/) package by Ted Ersek. It introduces new special symbols `DotEqual` and `LongRightArrow` which works like `Set` and `Rule` but provide variable scoping during evaluation of the RHS:

```
<< LocalPatterns.m

?DotEqual
```

> `lhs\[DotEqual]rhs` evaluates `rhs` using a local environment for any variable used as a pattern in `lhs`.  From then on `lhs` is replaced by the result of evaluating `rhs` whenever `lhs` appears. The infix operator `\[DotEqual]` is entered as `\[DotEqual]`.  The expression `lhs\[DotEqual]rhs`, has an equivalent form `LocalSet[lhs,rhs]`.

```
Clear[f];
x = 53.54;
f[x_] \[DotEqual] Integrate[Log[Sqrt[x] + 1], x]

Definition[f]
```

> f[x_] := Sqrt[x] - x/2 + (-1 + x) Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]

```
?LongRightArrow
```

> `lhs → rhs` represents a rule where `rhs` is evaluated immediately using a local environment for any variable used as a pattern in `lhs`.  The infix operator `→` is entered as `\[LongRightArrow]`. The expression `lhs → rhs` has an equivalent form `LocalRule[lhs,rhs]`.

```
x = 34/7;
g2 = g[x_]\[LongRightArrow]Integrate[Log[Sqrt[x] + 1], x]
```

> ```
> g[x_] :> Sqrt[x] - x/2 + (-1 + x) Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]
> ```