# Function incorrectly renaming variables in Rule Pattern

Tags: variable-definitions, rule, pure-function

Consider the simple pure `Function` containing a `Rule` with the named pattern `q`.

```
f = Function[{t}, q_ -> t]
```

When this function is called, it renames the pattern name to `q$`:

```
f[2]

>>> q$_ -> 3
```

This is quite strange, since there was clearly no variable collision in the function definition:

```
f
>>> Function[{t}, q_ -> t]
```

The [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) for `Function` includes:

> The named formal parameters `xi` in `Function[{x1,…},body]` are treated as
> local, and are renamed `xi$` when necessary to avoid confusion with
> actual arguments supplied to the function.

This doesn't seem to explain what's happening here, since an enclosed *pattern* `q` was renamed, instead of the "named formal parameters" `t` (which didn't need remaining anyway!).

Naturally passing symbols to the function shows the same behaviour:

```
f[a]
>>> q$_ -> a
```

*however* passing a symbol which happens to be the function variable (in this case `t`) prevents the renaming!

```
f[t]
>>> q_ -> t
```

Funnily enough, `Function` doesn't even rename the formal or pattern variables when they actually *do* collide (though of course, which symbol is which cannot be determined)!

```
f = Function[{t}, t_ -> t]
>>> Function[{t}, t_ -> t]

f[2]
>>> t_ -> t
```

What's going on here? What determines `Function`'s variable renaming (and why does it include scoped expressions despite the doc's explanation)? Is this a bug?

Furthermore, how can I prevent or revert this renaming? I wish to display the enclosed rule `q_ -> t` verbatim, when the function is called.

I'm using version "11.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)"

Comment: This tutorial section may be relevant: [Variables in pure functions and Rules](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThings.html#1131). I am not sure that it completely explains the behavior, but you may also be interested in [How to scope pattern labels in Rule / Set](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119876/27951).

Comment: `With[{t = 2}, t_ -> t]` also fails to make the replacement.

Comment: @MarcoB this part is definitely relevant "The Wolfram Language renames formal parameters in pure functions more liberally than is strictly necessary. In principle, renaming could be avoided if the names of the formal parameters in a particular function do not actually conflict with parts of expressions substituted into the body of the pure function. For uniformity, however, the Wolfram Language still renames formal parameters even in such cases"

Comment: I do not see how the behavior is "incorrect". It seems more to lie in the area of undefined/undocumented behavior. That said, the emulation of lexical scoping does leave a bit to be desired.

Comment: @MarcoB Ah yep, that indeed explains "The Wolfram Language has several 'scoping constructs' in which certain names are treated as local. When you mix these constructs in any way, the Wolfram Language does appropriate renamings to avoid conflicts". Thankyou!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is a product of Mathematica's lexical-scoping algorithm being efficient and just scoping anything that comes into comes into contact with a scoped variable (i.e. `t` in this case).

Here's some data that may or may not back that up.
First, the case at hand

```
Function[{t},
  {
   q_ -> {q, t},
   z_ -> x,
   z_ :> x,
   t_ :> t
   }
  ][1]

{q$_ -> {q$, 1}, z_ -> x, z_ :> x, t_ :> t}
```

We see that for the other scoped symbols, nothing happens. Interestingly, `Function` is not doing value injection, since the second `t` isn't affected.

Compare that to a regular function definition

```
meh[t_] :=
  {
   q_ -> {q, t},
   z_ -> x,
   z_ :> x,
   t_ :> t
   };
meh[1]

(* RuleDelayed::rhs: Pattern t_ appears on the right-hand side of rule meh[t_]:>{q_->{q,t},z_->x,z_:>x,t_:>t}. *)

{q$_ -> {q$, 1}, z_ -> x, z_ :> x, Pattern[1, _] :> 1}
```

We see clearly that the same lexical scoping happens, but in this case the `t` value *is* injected everywhere.

Now trying this with `With`, which should do pure injection

```
With[{t = 1},
 {
  q_ -> {q, t},
  z_ -> x,
  z_ :> x,
  t_ :> t
  }
 ]

{q$_ -> {q$, 1}, z_ -> x, z_ :> x, t_ :> t}
```

we see that the `t` is actually untouched. My hypothesis is that the lexical scoping algorithm has a set of heads that it doesn't touch, and the LHS of `Rule` is one of them. I know `Rule` and `RuleDelayed` have a lot of special properties like `SequenceHold`. This might just be another one of those.

For the purest injection possible, we can use `ReplaceAll`

```
ReplaceAll[
 {
  q_ -> {q, t},
  z_ -> x,
  z_ :> x,
  t_ :> t
  },
 t :> 1
 ]

{q_ -> {q, 1}, z_ -> x, z_ :> x, Pattern[1, _] :> 1}
```

this does no scoping and just replaces `t` wherever it sees it.

Just to round things out, `Block`/`Module` behave exactly like `With`, which is unsurprising given that `Block` respects `Hold` and the scoping algorithm used in `With` is the same one as in `Module` (I think) but with different scoped names.

```
Block[{t = 1},
 {
  q_ -> {q, t},
  z_ -> x,
  z_ :> x,
  t_ :> t
  }
 ]

{q_ -> {q, 1}, z_ -> x, z_ :> x, t_ :> t}

Module[{t = 1},
 {
  q_ -> {q, t},
  z_ -> x,
  z_ :> x,
  t_ :> t,
  t_ -> t
  }
 ]

{q$_ -> {q$, 1}, z_ -> x, z_ :> x, t_ :> t, t_ -> t}
```

This is not a definitive answer by any means, but I think it provides some data in favor of it just being the way Mathematica does lexical scoping.
I'm guessing that this is just an efficient way to do this, given that the internal `MExpr` object that represents Mathematica expressions (totally conjecture that there is one, but conjecture based on lots of hints and tips from WRI employees) can be treated as a tree and therefore can probably efficiently tell you what symbols are *in* and expression, but can't exactly tell you where. Easier to scope all of the symbols than to walk the tree and replace only the ones touched by the scoping construct explicitly.

One final bit of input, I think `Function` is smart when it's given `t` as an input and simply returns the function body without scoping. This is just an efficient short-cut for a common case. Here's my data for that statement

```
Function[
  {t},
  {
   q_ -> {q, t},
   z_ -> x,
   z_ :> x,
   t_ :> t
   },
  HoldAll
  ][t]

{q_ -> {q, t}, z_ -> x, z_ :> x, t_ :> t}

t = 5;
Function[
  {t},
  {
   q_ -> {q, t},
   z_ -> x,
   z_ :> x,
   t_ :> t
   },
  HoldAll
  ][t]

{q_ -> {q, 5}, z_ -> x, z_ :> x, t_ :> t}
```

as long as it sees `t` explicitly as input, it doesn't scope `q`.

Answer (score 3):

It may not be obvious at first sight but `Function[{t},q_->t]` is a nest of automatic name scoping constructs: `Function` outside and `Rule` inside.  The list of scoping constructs is given in [Modularity and the Naming of Things](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThings.html#1131), referred to by [MarcoB](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/27951/marcob) above.  See also [Scoping Constructs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ScopingConstructs.html), referred to in the documentation of `Function`.

In `Function`, renaming applies to formal parameters (the first argument of `Function`).  In `Rule`, renaming applies to pattern names.  Renaming is also known as α-conversion.

It may be more clear to rewrite your example as

```
In[2]:= Function[t,Rule[u_,x[t,u]]]@v
Out[2]= u$_->x[v,u$]
```

where `x` is any function, truly depending on `t` (in your example `x[t_,u_]:=t`).

The Wolfram language renames "more liberally than is strictly necessary".  In my example, renaming would be necessary only if `Unevaluated@u==v`, depending on the value of `v`.  The Wolfram language does not check this condition, it always renames as soon as a possibility of name conflict or collision exists (`x` depends on `t`), so it is lazy and excessively cautious but "faithful" to partial function "semantics".

The documentation is somehow laconic and euphemistic. When it says "By convention, `x$` is never used as a global name.", this actually means that you can use `x$` but it will never be renamed, at your own risk.

Coming back to the question, thus it is possible to avoid renaming like this:

```
In[9]:= Function[{t},q$_->t]@2
Out[9]= q$_->2
```

where `q$` has not been renamed `q$$`.  Indeed, renamed `q$` is `q$`, renaming is idempotent.

This has two interests: it provides a neat way to deactivate renaming and (for the WL developers) it simplifies the programming of scoping constructs (and possibly improves the performance).

This is funny too:

```
In[10]:= Function[{t},q$$_->t]@2
Out[10]= q$$$_->2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In[28]:= q_ -> # &@2
Out[28]= q_ -> 2
```