# Conflict with variables in pure functions

Tags: pure-function, localization

Consider the following snippet of code.

```
Clear[f, g]
f[x_] := Function[{i}, x];
g[h_] := Module[{Z},
   Z[i_] := Print[h];
   Print[h];
   Z[1];
];
```

When `g[f[2]]` is called, the first `Print` correctly returns `Function[{i$},2]`, while the second `Print` returns an error with `Function[{1},2]` as the output. The error arises from a conflict between the two local variables `i`'s in `f` and `Z`. In general, Mathematica automatically renames variables to avoid conflict, as described [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules.html).

Why is there a conflict in this case? Other than choosing an alternative variable name, what are the useful guidelines one should follow to avoid such conflicts?

Comment: The problem is that MMA thinks there is no conflict, right?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Not so much related but this is a nice topic about understanding of scoping in mma [75323](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75323/5478)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using

```
SetSystemOptions["StrictLexicalScoping" -> True]
```

will fix this.

Related (long reading!):

- [I define a variable as local to a module BUT then the module uses its global value! Why?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72758/12)

Comment: Also see comment thread under [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42351/12).

Comment: Is "StrictLexicalScoping" documented anywhere?

Comment: @anon I linked to the sources I am aware of.

Comment: Thank you. In summary, lexical scoping in MMA has flaws, and "StrictLexicalScoping" developed by Daniel Lichtblau at Wolfram attempts to fix these issues. Currently, this method is still under development, and is not perfect.

Comment: Szabolcs, I have been using the template **Bug introduced in x.x and fixed in x.x.x** for bug headers.  If you would be willing to adopt it I think it would make future searches easier.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

```
 SetAttributes[g, HoldFirst]
```

will solve your conflict here. To make this plausible, look at this line inside of your Module:

```
 Z[i_]:=Print[h]
```

Without `HoldFirst` this will look for the Kernel like:

```
 Z[i_]:= Print[Function[{i}, 2]]
```

when `h` is set to `f[2] := Function[{i},2]`, so the `i` inside of your functions definition is now by mistake recognizes as the pattern `i_`, what you dont want.
With the Attribute HoldFirst the assignment effectively looks like this:

```
 Z[i_]:=Print[f[2]]
```

then in this case, i inside of `f[2]` is not recognizes as the Pattern `i_` and you dont get these conflicts.

Here is the example:

```
SetAttributes[g, HoldFirst]
g[f[2]]
```

Out:

```
Function[{i$},2]

Function[{i$},2]
```