# Spurious renaming in nested Function construct

Tags: pure-function, iteration

From the documentation of Function, I take this example (slightly simplified). Renaming the dummy or bound variable (`y->y$` in the inner `Function`) is necessary in:

```
In[1206]:= Function[x, Function[y, f[x, y]]][y]
Out[1206]= Function[y$, f[y, y$]]
```

so that, for example,

```
In[1215]:= Function[x, Function[y, f[x, y]]][y][1]
Out[1215]= f[y, 1]
```

because

```
In[1211]:= Function[y$, f[y, y$]][1]
Out[1211]= f[y, 1]
```

Without renaming, we would obtain a different and generally wrong value

```
In[1212]:= Function[y, f[y, y]][1]
Out[1212]= f[1, 1]
```

The documentation shows that renaming occurs even if it is not necessary:

```
In[1213]:= Function[x, Function[y, f[x, y]]][1]
Out[1213]= Function[y$, f[1, y$]]
```

Indeed, the choice of parameter name `y` should have no consequence on the function value.

Now let me try:

```
 In[1214]:= Function[x, Function[y, f[x, y]]][y$]
 Out[1214]= Function[y$, f[y$, y$]]
```

which is the same as `Function[y, f[y, y]]` that is wrong, as explained above.

So it looks to me like a plain fat bug, is not it?

**Edited after comments**

The bug is equivalent to:

```
In[1335]:= With[{x = y$}, Function[y, f[x, y]]]
Out[1335]= Function[y$, f[y$, y$]]
```

In this related case on the contrary no renaming occurs:

```
In[1338]:= Function[y, f[x, y]] /. x -> y$
Out[1338]= Function[y, f[y$, y]]
```

That is because the job of `ReplaceAll` is just to replace, not to detect name conflict.

Comment: It's been there, probably since the beginning, but at least since v2, when I used the same "trick" as in your last example to solve a programming problem I didn't understand until I had been on this site for a couple of years — a long time spent in ignorance. I was always worried that they would change the renaming convention to use `Unique` or some such thing that couldn't be hacked. But the simple rule is, "Don't ever end your variables with a $." (A similar renaming occurs in `DynamicModule`, but with `$$`.)

Comment: Fortunately no problem with y$$.  So a remaining question is: is this the only case of automatic renaming by appending a single \$?  If so, avoiding single \$-ending names will be relatively safe.  I had in mind that `Block` was using internally single \$-ending name but I can't prove it so I was probably mistaken.

Comment: There's an extensive discussion of renaming in the tutorial "Modularity and the Naming of Things", esp. [this section](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThings.html#1131).  `Block[]` does not rename variables. `Module[]` and `DynamicModule[]` rename variables, but they use a different mechanism than the one you're discussing.

Comment: You can search on site for "lexical scoping" to see some discussion and how to solve various problems.  This might be the most relevant here, but there are others: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119403/is-the-renaming-mechanism-of-with-flawed/119410#119410

Comment: The no single $ ended name rule can be formally backed by this case `Function[t, Function[u$, t + u$]]@u$` where name conflict should be resolved by `u$$` but is not.   Amazingly, `Function[t, Function[u$$, t + u$$]]@u$$` resolves name conflict with `u$$$`.  This is weird.

Comment: Yes, so it is `With` (not `Block`) that also uses single $-ended names internally. The above link shows that `With` has nearly the same problem as `Function` and indeed `With[{x=y},f[x]]` may not be discernible from `Function[x,f[x]][y]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `$` signs at the end of variable names in `Function` in `Manipulate`, you're asking for trouble.

```
Manipulate[
 Function[x, Function[y, f[x, y$]]][y$$],
 {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 y$$$ + y$$$$ + y$$$$$ + Function[x, Function[y, f[x, y]]][y$$],
 {y$$$$$, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 y$$$ + y$$$$ + y$$$$$ + Function[x, Function[y, f[x, y]]][y$$$],
 {y$$$$$, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

The explanation is that `Manipulate` strips and adds dollar signs according to its own secret rules, maybe after thumb wrestling with `Function`, which is not really an explanation. The results always seem to be the same. Maybe not from version to version. I didn't check.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of `Function` in Mathematica:

> The named formal parameters `Subscript[x, i]` in
> `Function[{Subscript[x, 1],\[Ellipsis]},body]`
> are treated as local, and are renamed
> `Subscript[x, i]$` when necessary to avoid confusion with actual
> arguments supplied to the function.

One missing information in this laconic description is that single \$-ended formal parameters, corresponding to the string expression `___ ~~ Except@"$" ~~ "$"`, e. g. `t$`, but not `t$$`, are never renamed.

The renaming mechanism (called α-conversion in λ-calculus) appears in the minimal case

```
In[3]:= Function[t, Function[u, y[t, u]]]@v
Out[3]= Function[u$, y[v, u$]]
```

Semantically, for a faithful model of a mathematical (partial) function, renaming is only needed if the value of `v` is `u` (`v==u`):

```
In[4]:= Function[t, Function[u, y[t, u]]]@u
Out[4]= Function[u$, y[u, u$]]
```

The Wolfram language model of function is thus overcautious.  For example, renaming occurs without need in

```
In[7]:= Function[t, Function[u, y[t, u]]]@1
Out[7]= Function[u$, y[1, u$]]
```

I suppose that this overcautiousness is intended by design to save the test `u==v` run time.

If ever you want to avoid unneeded renaming, you can, by using single \$-ended in the first place:

```
In[9]:= Function[t, Function[u$, y[t, u$]]]@1
Out[9]= Function[u$, y[1, u$]]
```

Thus [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2)'s rule "Don't ever end your variables with a \$." is safe but also overcautious for the following reasons:

1. Single \$-ended names are useful (or intended by design) to avoid renaming.
2. Names ending with at least two \$ like `t$$` are perfectly safe for `Function` (although elsewhere I can't assert).