# Slots inside nested pure functions

Tags: functions, core-language, pure-function

I'd like `/@` instead of `Table` or `Map`.
But let we have it inside pure function:

```
{#1, (#1 + #) & /@ #2} &[a, {b, c, d, e, ...}]
```

It is assumed that the second `#1` should be the same as first - *a first argument of a main function*. So output should be:

```
{a, {a + b, a + c, ...}}
```

But of course according to the rules of Wolfram Language
the second `#1` stands for first argument of inner function, so output is:

```
{a, {2 b, 2 c, 2 d, ...}}
```

Is it possible to avoid Table in this case?

#### Clarification

In documentation there is an example: Horner nested polinomial:

```
Fold[x #1 + #2 &, 0, {a, b, c, d, e}]
```

I need a pure function instead of function of x, and short (for code-golf challenges).
The ways suggested in the answers are not suitable in this case.

Comment: `{#1,  #1 + #2} &[a,  {b,  c}]`

Comment: See also [Pure function inside another pure function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38393/142).  Also, note [the perils](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261401/142) of using `Function` with named arguments.

Answer (score 7):

Plus is Listable:

```
{#1, #1 + #2} &[a, {b, c}]
```

But more generally, you can always use the full, explicit form of Function:

```
{#1, Function[x, #1 + x] /@ #2} &[a, {b, c}]
```

Or

```
Function[{addend, list}, {addend, Function[x, addend + x] /@ list}][a, {b, c}]
```

Some alternates to represent the case where the function we're mapping is non-Listable.

```
{#1, Thread[f[#1, #2]]} &[a, {b, c, d, e}]
(*{a,{f[a,b],f[a,c],f[a,d],f[a,e]}}*)

{#1, Function[x, f[#1, x], Listable][#2]} &[a, {b, c, d, e}]
(*{a,{f[a,b],f[a,c],f[a,d],f[a,e]}}*)
```

Comment: But what if we have big list, or/and non-listable operator?

Comment: The length of the list shouldn't matter. If the operator isn't listable, you can use the Function[...] form (I updated the answer) or you can actually set attributes of a Function (so write the Function as just appling the operator you want, but add a third argument of Listable).

Comment: Thread might work here as well for non-listable operators.

Comment: Don't forget there's also the `Function` shorthand `({x, y} |-> {x, f[x, #] & /@ y})[a, {b, c}]`

Answer (score 3):

It seems `ReplaceAll` is suitable for all cases:

```
{x, (x + #) & /@ #2} /. x -> #1 &[a, {b, c, d, e}]
```

Output: `{a, {a + b, a + c, a + d, a + e}}`

```
f = Fold[x #1 + #2 &, 0, {a, b, c, d}] /. x -> # &;
f@2
```

Output: `2 (2 (2 a + b) + c) + d`