# Pure function on pure function

Tags: list-manipulation, pure-function

Given

```
t1 = {2, 4, 8, 16};
t2 = {1, 5, 9};
First[Select[t1, # > 1 &]]     
First[Select[t1, # > 5 &]]
First[Select[t1, # > 9 &]]
```

can somehow be summarized by

```
 Table[First[Select[t1, # > x &]], {x, t2}]
```

to get the correct result

```
{2, 8, 16}
```

Is there a way to use two pure functions connected instead of working around the problem by using `Table`?
Something like (which does not work!):

```
First[Select[t1, # > # &] & /@ t2]
```

Comment: possible duplicate: [279200](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/279200/5478)

Comment: `With[{x=#},SelectFirst[t1,#>x&]]&/@t2`

Comment: Related [Pure function inside another pure function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38393/106)

Comment: We should really call these anonymous functions when using slots `#`, because technically [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) are not supposed to affect mutable state or produce different values given identical arguments, but Mathematica's 'pure' functions can do this, e.g: `x = 1; f = (++x; x + #) &; {f[1],f[1],f[1]}`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are 2 suggestions:

```
First @ Select[t1, GreaterThan[#]] & /@ t2
Function[x, First @ Select[t1, # > x &]] /@ t2
```

## Edit

Or, if you want to go really abstract:

```
Map[
 First@Select[t1,
    OperatorApplied[Function[#1 > #2]][#1]
    ] &,
 t2
 ]
```

Comment: `SelectFirst[t1, GreaterThan[#]] & /@ t2` but at some point `Function` is the way to go anyway.

Comment: Using  `|->` syntax you can avoid `Function` e.g: `(x |-> SelectFirst[t1, # > x &]) /@ t2`

Comment: Look Ma, no Slots: `Through[(SelectFirst /@ GreaterThan /@ t2) @ t1]` :p

Comment: @flinty  What does |-> stand for? I use Mathematica 12.1 and I get an error.

Comment: @user57467 It was added in 12.2 as a short hand for `Function`, so one can do things like `x|->x^2`.

Answer (score 7):

Just another way to do this using `GroupBy` and `Lookup`:

```
Lookup[GroupBy[t1, GreaterThan[#], First] & /@ t2, True]

(*{2, 8, 16}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {2, 4, 8, 16};

b = {1, 5, 9};
```

Using `FirstCase`

```
FirstCase[a, x_ /; x > #] & /@ b
```

> {2, 8, 16}