# Why patterns names aren't scoped by default?

Tags: scoping, implementation-details, language-design

In a recent question [[1]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119876/5478) OP asked how to make `Module` scope working inside `Set`, so how to get:

> ```
> f[x$123_] = x$123
> ```

instead of

> ```
> f[x_] = x
> ```

from

```
Module[{x}, Defer[f[x_] = x] ]
```

It is stated in Details of `Module` ref page that:

> Before evaluating `expr`, `Module` substitutes new symbols for each of the local variables that appear anywhere in `expr` **except as local variables in scoping constructs.**

**My question** is - why this exception is present? What common usage cases dictated this behaviour? Does this makes something safer?

I don't complain, I'm just curious. I don't know why Module can't just change every `x` it sees to `x$1232`? Current rule looks like an exception which causes only troubles.

---

It is even more interesting when we introduce `y` which will rename `x`

```
Module[{x , y = 1},
 Defer[f[x_] = x y]
 ]
```

> ```
> f[x$_] = x$ y$7519
> ```

[1] [How to scope `Pattern` labels in rules/set?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119876/5478)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't follow everything.  Is this about weirdness like this?  `x = 1;
Module[{x = 2}, Print[x_ -> x]]` Note how the `x` *within the Module* is actually evaluating to its global value.

Comment: `SetSystemOptions["StrictLexicalScoping" -> True]` fixes that.

Comment: [Is this a duplicate?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42351/12)  Be sure to read all the comments.  I asked there why StrictLexicalScoping is not turned on by default.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm aware of that option but it gives `f[x$_] = x$` not `x$1231`. Moreover, the question is why a particular implementation was chosen.

Comment: We can also use Block instead of Module here as a kind of workaround.  I know that brings its own issues.

Comment: @Szabolcs yes, I should add your comments to the question so it's clear those things are known. Yep `Block` has own issues, here [20766](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/5478) `Block` fixes it but `expr` (and all symbols that are really temporary) shouldn't be `Block's` variables, yet mixing `Block` and  `Module` will generate the problem again...

Comment: @Szabolcs ... So here we are again, why something like that isn't default, why won't `Module` change every `x` it sees to `x$1232`? inner scoping constructs can deal with this, inner `Module` will further rename to `x$1232$1233` so why not? That seems like a clear rule and meanwhile we have to workaround renaming that was supposed to make life easier. Again, StrictLexicalScoping isn't the answer here, `x$` is not enough imo.

Comment: @Szabolcs just for the record, while both questions ask "why" my asks for something different so I don't agree it is a duplicate. Also, I have rephrased the question, is it clearer maybe?

Comment: I didn't vote to close, I just put the link there ...

Comment: @Szabolcs sure, but you asked a question so I answered ;)

Comment: Closely related, perhaps a duplicate candidate: [(72758)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72758/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard While Leonid says he will explain "what and why" he rather explains "what and how". There is a statement "such renaming h -> h$123 has to be prevented." which my question really ask about. Why it has to be prevented. You have started to explain it too but with not real examples "why" it is not desired for `Set` and `Rule`. So if you want to extend your thought about that specific part, here is a good place ;)

Comment: The last sample can be further simplified: `Module[{y}, Defer[f[x_] = x y]]`