# Scoping problem?

Tags: scoping

Why

```
(f[1, 0] /. {x : 0 | 1 :> 1 - x}) -> 0
```

returns (expectedly) `f[0, 1] -> 0`, while

```
Module[{x}, (f[1, 0] /. {x : 0 | 1 :> 1 - x}) -> 0]
```

returns `f[1 - x$2749, 1 - x$2749] -> 0`? I can not imagine a consistent explanation for this behavior. There since Mma 7 at least.

Comment: Your problem is that you declare a local variable with the same name as a pattern. Module replaces all local names by a unique name with the exception of pattern names. It does not realize that the `x` in the rules belongs to a pattern.  If you consider this a bug, please report it to support@wolfram.com

Comment: It is the way WL ensures that the `x` scoped to the `Module` is different from `x` in the outer scope. Check the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThings.html). Use `Block` (and be aware of the other differences) to avoid generated symbols.

Comment: Note that while I mentioned [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42351/variable-scoping-in-module) as a direct duplicate, I think that a somewhat more detailed explanation is given e.g. in [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91917/strange-behavior-with-cases-and-position-with-setdelayed) and references therein.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, related, but not exactly a duplicate as in your reference the inner rule appears in the right-hand side of the outer one, while in the present question it appears in the left-hand side. Even more important, in your reference the behavior does not depend on the outer `Module[{a,b},...]`, e.g.,
`a = 3;(x /. Replace[{x, t}, {a_, b_} -> a -> b])`
returns `x`.

Comment: @RomaLee My point is that the puzzling behavior in all these cases has the same origin. If you look into those other cases and read explanations in the related Q/As and references therein, that should give you a good idea about the reasons for this behavior, also in your particular case.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin The two examples you mentioned are at least cured with `SetSystemOptions["StrictLexicalScoping" -> True]`, but mine is not. So, I suppose, the similarity between those three cases can be worded as  "nested `Rule`/`RuleDelayed` scoping constructs are unreliable"? Or is there a more specific wording?

Comment: @RomaLee Well, yours is cured by e.g. this: `Module[{x}, With[{r = Rule}, r[f[1, 0] /. {x : 0 | 1 :> 1 - x}, 0]]]`. Read the references I linked, and references therein, for explanations. In particular, [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46613/81).  I also recommend [this general Q/A on the topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20766/enforcing-correct-variable-bindings-and-avoiding-renamings-for-conflicting-varia). Your formulation *"nested Rule/RuleDelayed scoping constructs are unreliable"* is not bad, perhaps a little too general.

Comment: I don't think the question that this is currently marked as a duplicate of (Variable scoping in Module) should be linked to as the duplicate, as the top-voted answer is not accepted and, more importantly, does not address the issue, which is ultimately lexical scoping in nested rules. However, I do believe other questions linked here by @LeonidShifrin have answers which address the issue, and essentially find what I find below—perhaps the last one (linked to by "this one") is most informative about what is going on. One of those should be the duplicate, not the current one, I think.

Comment: @thorimur You may be right. If you have a strong opinion about this and enough energy, you could take it to the mods - at this point only them could change it. I personally don't care all that much - as long as all relevant questions are linked and mentioned in comments, because I don't think there is a single exact duplicate here. Rather, all these questions belong to the same category, illustrating various aspects of the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately, the culprit is not *simply* the lexical scoping of `Module`, as comments have mentioned, but the scoping rules for `Rule` and `RuleDelayed`.

**tl;dr:** `x_` appears to belong to the scope of the outermost `->`, not the innermost `:>`, and so `x` is not lexically scoped by `:>`—even though it would be lexically scoped and protected from replacement in `Module` in other cases, e.g. if we got rid of the top-level rule.

The following is a long discussion about the issue.

#### What's not the problem: how `Module` behaves with rules

I want to contribute a few more examples, which I think illustrate how both the rule scoping and module scoping works:

```
 In[1]:=  x = 100; (x_ :> x + 1) -> 0

Out[1]:=  (x_ :> x + 1) -> 0

 In[2]:=  x = 100; (5 /. x_ :> x + 1) -> 0

Out[2]:=  6 -> 0

 In[3]:=  Module[{x = 100}, x_ :> x + 1]

Out[3]:=  x_ :> x + 1

 In[4]:=  Module[{x = 100}, (x_ :> x + 1) -> 0]

Out[4]:=  (x_ :> x$90724 + 1) -> 0

 In[5]:=  Module[{x = 100}, (5 /. x_ :> x + 1) -> 0]

Out[5]:=  101 -> 0

 In[6]:=  Module[{x = 100}, Hold[x]]

Out[6]:=  Hold[x$98978]
```

Note that all of the above behavior remains if we replace `->` with `:>`.

These are a lot of examples all at once, but we'll use them.

Importantly, changing `Module` to `Block` produces the "expected behavior" in `Out[1]` and `Out[2]`. `Module` uses *lexical* scoping, while `Block` uses *dynamic* scoping.

To see how this works, consider `In`s `4`, `5`, and `6`. They show that even held expressions get their variables renamed. `:>` has the attribute `HoldRest`, meaning that its latter part is held. In `In[5]`, `x$NNNNN` is released from its hold via the use of `/.`, and evaluated. (This also shows us that variables are initialized only *after* renaming takes place; giving a symbol a definition is a dynamic operation, not a lexical one.)

But, even though `Module` renames held symbols, it avoids renaming lexically bound symbols.

This means that for `Module` the free symbols (ones that are not local to another construct inside it) are renamed before evaluation; for an example of a symbol that *is* local to a construct inside module, and therefore not renamed, consider `Module[{x = 5}, Module[{x = 3}, x]]`, which returns `3`.

This is supposed to be the case for `Rule`s too. From the documentation for `Rule`:

> Symbols that occur as pattern names in lhs are treated as local to the rule. This is true when the symbols appear on the right-hand side of /; conditions in lhs, and when the symbols appear anywhere in rhs, even inside other scoping constructs.

Further, consider the statement from the documentation for `RuleDelayed`:

> `Module` and `With` do not affect local variables of `RuleDelayed`

with the example

```
In[7] :=  Module[{x = 1}, a /. x_ :> x + 1]

Out[7]:=  1 + a
```

which is equivalent to our `In[3]`.

#### So, what's happening here?

Let's describe what happens in the case of `In[3]`. `:>` looks at the symbols on its rhs, sees which appear as pattern names on its lhs, then binds them to be local to the rule, protecting them from `Module`'s lexical scoping.

In contrast, in the case of `In[4]`, I believe that **the `x_` on the lhs of `x_ :> x + 1` belongs to the scope of the *outermost* `Rule`, not the innermost `RuleDelayed`**, and is therefore **not a symbol on the rhs of `:>` which is named by a pattern on its lhs, and so is not bound by `:>`**. Further, since the outermost `Rule` does not consider symbols on its lhs which do not name patterns, such as `x`, to be local, it releases `x` to be bound and renamed by `Module`.

(Note again that the distinction between `Rule` and `RuleDelayed` is only relevant insofar as `RuleDelayed` has the attribute `HoldRest` and holds `x + 1`; replacing `Rule` with `RuleDelayed` produces the same behavior.)

This is unusual to me. I personally think the `x_` there should belong to the scope of the inner `:>`, not the outer `->`.

To bolster the notion that this is in fact what is going on, consider the following, which shows the latter-mentioned fact that symbols on the lhs of `Rule` don't get lexically bound by named patterns on the lhs:

```
In[8] :=  Module[{x = 100}, Hold[{x_, x} -> x]

Out[8]:=  Hold[{x_, x$100384} -> x]
```

This shows us that the `x` named by a pattern on the lhs is only in the scope of `Rule` when it's on its rhs. Otherwise, it's not local to `Rule`, and `Module` grabs it.

This is fine. The issue is, as you've pointed out, when there's an inner rule which seems like it ought to lexically scope the `x`, and doesn't! So, take another look at `In[4]` now; note that `x` acts like any other symbol appearing on the lhs of `Rule`, instead of being lexically bound by being on the rhs of `:>`.

Your example corroborates the first notion: if `x_` belonged to `:>`, then `x` would be lexically scoped in the `:>` expression, and the replacement would proceed as expected.

#### Is this behavior good for users?

I can maybe understand why one might want the above behavior: then all patterns in the lhs of any rule are indeed patterns for that rule, which you could use in replacements. But this is still true even if you change the lexical scoping rules to make them more intuitive, since evaluation essentially implements the expected scoping behavior via attributes like `HoldRest`. In contrast, as we've seen, `Hold`s are transparent to lexical scoping.

The main thing wrong with it for me, really, is the **unexpected** failure of lexical scoping with nested rules, which is, as far as I can tell, not necessary for dynamic evaluation to behave as expected even in cases where one wants to use a whole rule as a pattern for a replacement—but I could be wrong on that.

Why should a user expect `In[2]` to produce different output than `In[5]`? The lexical scoping is "not compatible" with the dynamic scoping. Admittedly, in many cases this is exactly what we want. We want to transform held expressions in place before evaluating, as `Module` and `With` do.

The problem is that the evaluation rules create the appearance of lexical scoping while using a different mechanism, which makes the apparent scoping in `In[2]` (`x = 100; (5 /. x_ :> x + 1) -> 0`) a red herring. It works for a reason one wouldn't expect it to, given how `Module` *does* respect lexical scoping by `:>`: the `x` here only *appears* well-scoped because it is held.

In either case, I think granting the lexical scope to the outermost rule instead of the innermost one (assuming that I'm correct in that being what's happening) is counterintuitive for the user, and relies on evaluation timing instead of the apparent scoping suggested by both the syntax highlighter and the behavior in `Module` in non-nested cases. I'd be curious why the decision was made to grant the outermost rule lexical priority!

Comment: So, the outermost rule seems to not evaluate its left hand-side prior to checking for patterns? This is strange.

Comment: So, because it's a matter of *lexical* scoping, not dynamic i.e. evaluation-based scoping, my understanding is that which symbols are local/in what lexical scope (i.e. checking for patterns) is in a sense determined before *any* evaluation takes place at all. it's only a matter of syntactic expression structure, not evaluation order. That's just my understanding, though, and ofc I'm still learning exactly how Mathematica works!