# Strange Replace problem within RuleDelayed within function

Tags: replacement, scoping

I've run into a strange anomaly with `Replace` when it is performed inside the first argument of `RuleDelayed` within a function that includes one of its parameters as the second argument to the same `RuleDelayed`.  Obscure, I know, and I can work around it, I'm sure, but it has me scratching my head.

`Replace` is finding a match, but is unable to utilize the pattern labels I provided on the RHS of the replacement expression. The problem goes away if I only replace at e.g. level `{0}` or if I don't use the function argument in the `RuleDelayed`... Any ideas?

See below:

```
ClearAll[ReplaceProblem]

ReplaceProblem[a_] := RuleDelayed[
  Replace[NotEvenUsing@AnyParameters, 
   f_[x : Except[_Pattern]] :> f[x]],
  a]

ReplaceProblemGone[a_] := RuleDelayed[
  Replace[NotEvenUsing@AnyParameters, 
   f_[x : Except[_Pattern]] :> f[x]],
  abc]

Column[#, Frame -> All] &@Trace@
  ReplaceProblem[a]

Column[#, Frame -> All] &@Trace@
  ReplaceProblemGone[a]
```

Output (bad version):

```
ReplaceProblem[a]
Replace[NotEvenUsing[AnyParameters],f$_[x$:Except[_Pattern]]:>f[x]]:>a
{{f$_[x$:Except[_Pattern]]:>f[x],f$_[x$:Except[_Pattern]]:>f[x]},Replace[NotEvenUsing[AnyParameters],f$_[x$:Except[_Pattern]]:>f[x]],f[x]}
f[x]:>a
f[x]:>a
```

Output (good version):

```
ReplaceProblemGone[a]
Replace[NotEvenUsing[AnyParameters],f_[x:Except[_Pattern]]:>f[x]]:>abc
{{f_[x:Except[_Pattern]]:>f[x],f_[x:Except[_Pattern]]:>f[x]},Replace[NotEvenUsing[AnyParameters],f_[x:Except[_Pattern]]:>f[x]],NotEvenUsing[AnyParameters]}
NotEvenUsing[AnyParameters]:>abc
NotEvenUsing[AnyParameters]:>abc
```

I seemed to have confused the automatic scoping rules somehow...?  Where did I break some rule???

Comment: This is another one of the issues with lexical scoping emulation in WL. The most recent one: [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/237876/scoping-problem). Check these Q/As for explanations: [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20766/enforcing-correct-variable-bindings-and-avoiding-renamings-for-conflicting-varia), [3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46611/stringreplace-replaceall-and-rule-interact-in-a-bizarre-way), [4](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91917/strange-behavior-with-cases-and-position-with-setdelayed), in that order.

Comment: And after that, you will understand why either of these two modifications of your code will fix it: `ClearAll[ReplaceProblem]; ReplaceProblem[a_] := RuleDelayed @@ 
Hold[Replace[NotEvenUsing@AnyParameters, f_[x : Except[_Pattern]] :> f[x]], a]`, or `ClearAll[ReplaceProblem]; ReplaceProblem[a_] := With[{rd = RuleDelayed}, rd[Replace[NotEvenUsing@AnyParameters, f_[x : Except[_Pattern]] :> f[x]], a]]`.

Comment: A response from the master himself!  Thanks @LeonidShifrin, reading through your linked material.

Comment: Glad to help. I hope those links were useful.